# ISAPI_Rewrite to change a directory / folder. is this right?

Tags: directory, isapi, isapi-rewrite

Our store app is in our `/store/` directory, and I want to move it to our main domain. We have tons of links on these URLs so I want to preserve them in the transfer over.

For example:

**http://www.mystore.com/store/hammer.aspx** would forward to the newly valid URL of **http://www.mystore.com/hammer.aspx**.

Sometimes our URLs have string data after the .aspx, so that also needs to transfer when in the original URL.

In ISAPI rewrite, if I update my .htaccess, would this code be correct:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mystore.com/store$  
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mystore.com/$1 [L,RP]
```

Is this correct?  I'm a little confused on the `/$1` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to fix your config as follows (for ISAPI_Rewrite v3):

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mystore\.com$
RewriteRule ^store(/.*\.aspx.*) $1 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*\.aspx.*)$ store/$1 [NC,L]
```